# jQuery and Ajax script explanation

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

Can someone please explain to me line by line what this script does I'm fairly lost. Results is a CSS `div` that displays some search later on.

```
61  var resultObject = $( "#results" );     
62  $( "a" ).click( function( anchor ){
63      anchor.preventDefault();
64      var linkObject = $( this );
65      $.ajax({
66          url: linkObject.attr( "href" ), 
67          type: "post",                   
68          dataType: "html",               
69          error: function(){
70              resultObject.html( "<p>Page Not Found!!</p>" );
71              },
72          success: function( newData ){
73              resultObject.html( newData );
74              }
75          });                         
77  });
78 });
```

Comment: which part are you confused about? which parts do you get? how much do you know about jquery/ajax?

Comment: I understand that resultobject is another variable for results

Comment: and what exactly do you think is `$("#results")` if i may ask

Comment: I understand that resultobject is another variable for results. I don't understand what the anchor function does. Preventdefault stops the click default from happening. If the function is not successful it will display that page is not found. I don't exactly what linkobject is. Post is the tpye of the request. HTML is the type of data thats returned. On success it will load the vraibles into NewData and then resultObject becomes newData. I might be wrong on some of these.

Comment: $("#results") is a div where the answer will be displayed.

Comment: `linkobject` is a handle to the specific link element that's having it's `onClick` event set. `this` is a reference to the DOM element of invocation. Basically every time you get a set of elements back, jQuery turns it into an array - `this` references the current item in that array.

Answer (score 1):

- 61 - Search the element with id equal to "results" and assigns to the variable resultObject;
- 62 - Assigns the click event to all elements of tag , the anchor object represents the event;
- 63 - Cancels the default event (I believe that to prevent the tag  make a POST);
- 64 - Transforms the clicked element (`<a>`) in a jQuery object, to use its functions;
- 65 - Performs an request ajax POST to the URL defined in the href attribute of the clicked element;
- 68 - Specifies that the data type is HTML;
- 70 - An error occurred in the AJAX request: the element with id "results" receives the content `<p> Page Not Found </ p>!`;
- 73 - Success in the AJAX request: the variable resultObject receives the content returned by the request URL.